# herokuにGoとJSで作成したアプリをデプロイするには

Tags: angularjs, go, heroku, デプロイ, grunt

サーバーサイドをGoで作成し、そのプロジェクトディレクトリの中にAngularJSとGruntを使って作成したフロントエンドの実装を書きました。そこで質問なのですが、GoのアプリをデプロイするときにGruntのタスクを走らせたりbowerやnpmのインストールをさせるということはできるのでしょうか、またできるとしてどうすればいいのでしょうか。

いろいろ調べましたが単体でデプロイする方法は書かれていますが。両方を同時にデプロイしかつgruntも実行するやりかたがわかりませんでした。どなたかわかるかた教えて下さい。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

herokuのコマンドによりbuildpackを複数使用することを記述できました。
今回の場合はgoとnode.js with gruntのbuildpackを用いました。